# how can I get the IP address without port from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is what I have:

```
[
     "218.200.188.34:13310",
     "218.200.188.46:11295",
     "218.200.188.34:17357"
]
```

and this is what I need:

```
[
     "218.200.188.34",
     "218.200.188.46",
     "218.200.188.34"
]
```

How can I get it with JS.

Comment: This is not json it's a string array but sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `map` to return a new array. The callback splits each element on the `:` and returns the first element of that array.

```
var out = arr.map(function (el) {
  return el.split(':')[0];
});
```

OUTPUT

```
[ "218.200.188.34", "218.200.188.46", "218.200.188.34" ]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n1ebzsnx/)

Comment: Clean solution. +no regex

Comment: RegExp is cleaner too.

Comment: Be careful with the solution, it doesn't work for IPv6

Comment: I wrote this answer 5 years ago. I can't predict the future. @mt_serg. I can only answer the question that was posted.

Comment: @Andy, no claims to your answer. Just want to warn those who seeking for the answer and not keeping in mind IPv6 format.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var p = ["218.200.188.34:13310", "218.200.188.46:11295", "218.200.188.34:17357" ] ;

var result = p.map(function($this){  
  return $this.substring(0,$this.indexOf(":"));
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your JSON and push into a new array the part you have `split` :

```
for(var i =0; i < jsonIp.length; i++){
    jsonIp2.push(jsonIp[i].split(":")[0]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j4de2953/